# Need to add/update the arguments of an durable rabbitmq queue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

I want to configure dead letter to my exisiting queue. For that, i tried adding arguments(x-dead-letter-queue) to my Durable rabbitmq queue. So when i updated my bean definition

From

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
   return QueueBuilder.durable("my-queue")
          .build();
```

To

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
   return QueueBuilder.durable("my-queue")
          .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", "dead-letter.exchange")
          .build();
}
```

i get an exception

```
Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'my-queue' in vhost '/': received 'dead-letter.exchange' but current is None, class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

I read that i could apply policy to update a durable queue. So, i tried the below command

`rabbitmqctl set_policy dlq_policy_name "my-queue" '{"dead-letter-exchange": "dead-letter.exchange"}'`

But still the arguments are not set on the queue my-queue.

Can you help me achieve this?

PS. I would rather avoid deleting and recreating the queue, but if it is the last option, then only i would consider that.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own post...

So, after setting policy, you don't see the policy setting in the arguments of the queue.

Checking

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues name arguments policy
```

would give you arguments as well as policies for a queue.

Then we would have to remove the argument setting in the java code and depending upon the policy set the queue would work.